# Installing multiarch debian package with architecture:all dependency

Tags: ubuntu, debian, packaging

This is a problem on [a personal ppa archive here](https://code.launchpad.net/~i30817/+archive/ubuntu/dosbox-patched)

One of the dependencies of the build dosbox is the (also made by me on another recipe) mt32romdata package. Its purpose is a simple script to install the ROMs during package installation by asking the user for them, and therefore manage the uninstall only after every using package is removed (every package that uses it, currently dosbox and exult, have patches applied to look for it where it puts the ROM).

This is a architecture indep package (ie : `Architecture: all` ; *not* any) since it's a simple post-inst script.

Exult and dosbox packages have it as dependency. Now the niggle: i want to be able to install dosbox:i386 (its JIT is much better in 32bits) and exult 64 bits. The actual lib32emu library is not a problem, since exult bundles its own version, so there are no conflicts there. The problem is that when i try:

```
apt-get install dosbox:i386
```

apt spits out:

```
dosbox:i386 : Depends: mt32romdata:i386 but it is not installable
```

Which i hope everyone understands goes against the spirit of architecture independent packages. Is this just a error in the dosbox package control file and i should have put the  runtime dependency as something different than:

```
Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}, mt32romdata
```

Or is it a limitation of multiarch support on ubuntu/debian?

A reminder that replacing 'all' by 'any' on the mt32romdata package control architecture definition does not appeal because both versions would conflict if i want to install dosbox:i386 and exult:amd64

Answer (score 1):

I believe i got it. This seems to be a problem of backwards compatibility that was dealt with with a new field, [Multiarch](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/Implementation#Multi-Arch:_foreign_support_packages)

Dosbox just so happens to be (rightfully) marked Multiarch: foreign, which means that the mt32romdata Architecture: all package also needs to be marked Multiarch: foreign according to the link.